# Throws an error unable to load assets there where I dont want any image

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with passing image constructor. I passed one image there where I wanted and it automatically added something to the rest, when I didnt want it.

I try to pass it from here

```
    class LvPopup extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String users_info;
  final String? image;
  LvPopup({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.users_info,
    this.image,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: TextStyle(color: PaidworkColors.lightTxtColor),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(image ?? ""),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      users_info,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

to there

```
LvPopup(
      title: 'E-mail',
      users_info: 'gmail.com',
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    LvPopup(
      users_info: 'Johny Bravo',
      title: 'Name and Surname',
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    LvPopup(
      image: 'assets/images/blue_dot.png',
      users_info: "In the process ",
      title: 'Status',
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    LvPopup(
      users_info: '+0.00',
      title: 'Earnings(USD)',
    ),
```

and the problem is that I want image only in:

```
 LvPopup(
  image: 'assets/images/blue_dot.png',
  users_info: "In the process ",
  title: 'Status',
),
```

but it throws an error to the rest and it says unable to load asset, when I dont want to pass image to the rest LvPopup only to that "Status"

here is an image:

[err img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdC4e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if image is null display SizedBox()

```
Row(
        children: [
          image != null ? Image.asset(image) : SizedBox(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Text(
              users_info,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the line
`Image.assets(image ?? "")`
if the variable image is null, then you are trying to show an image along the path with an empty string and you will get an error,
it's better to try this

```
image==null ?  null :  Image.assets(image)
```

Comment: You mean to paste "image==null ?  null :  Image.assets(image)" instead of "Image.assets(image ?? "")"??

Comment: If you can look at this: 
https://imgur.com/QPK49XS and this:
https://imgur.com/Bp1F2c5

Comment: you also have to add assets in your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: it is added https://imgur.com/a/hqQnsq9